# Flutter WebView window.close() not working (Android)

Tags: android, flutter, android-webview, flutterwebviewplugin, webview-flutter

I cannot close the opened web page using webview flutter with `window.close()` functionality.

I am using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) in my application. The website that I've been using has a `window.open()` function that will open a new window that contains different URL. Inside the new window, there is a close button to close the new window using `window.close()`. This is working fine when I test it using Browser in my laptop and mobile device, but not working when I tried it on a Flutter application using the above webview plugin.

I am receiving this warning in my logs when I tapped the close button.

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

I also tried other plugins like [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) , but no luck as well.

So I'm wondering if this feature for Flutter webview is already available?

Please help me, any suggestions or solutions is highly appreciated. Thank you all in advance!

**Update**:
Packages that I've been tested and still not working

- [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)
- [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

Comment: Have you tried opening the link in another webview?

Comment: @J.Wincewicz Yes, I tried it and the `window.close()` functionality from another webview is still not working.

Comment: hi @Tepits do you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: There is still nothing on this? 3 years on?

Answer (score -1):

try using this its simple and easy to use [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)  use the example in the readme

Comment: I've tried that package and it is not working as well.

Comment: wait how? I'm using this and it works perfectly. Try to use that in a clean flutter project